# Access and declaration of objects within other objects

Tags: java

I'm new to java so please excuse my simplicity.
How do I call on an object within another object in this case a GCompound. In the code below I want to make "flame" to blink. But it does not seem to be visible from the run method.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

public class BuildTower extends GraphicsProgram {

    GCompound Ekulobia;
    GCompound Dike_na_fia;
    GCompound Uli;
    GCompound Aniche;
    GCompound Achebe;
    GCompound Akuwanta;
    GCompound Ogbunike;
    GCompound Obinohia; 
    GCompound Aguata;

    private GCompound[] name = { Aguata, Ekulobia, Dike_na_fia, Uli, Aniche, Achebe, Akuwanta, Ogbunike, Obinohia } ;

    public void run() {
        setSize(800,300);
        GLabel towerName;   

        for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++ ) {
            towerName = new GLabel (nameTower(i));
            towerName.setFont("Times-12");
            name[i] = new erectTower(towerName);
            add(name[i],50 + i * 80,100);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++ ) {
            name[i].flame.setFilled(true);  /*cannot access flame in erecttower method*/
            pause (500);
            name[i].flame.setFilled(false);
            pause (700);
        }
    }

    private String nameTower(int n) {
        switch (n) {
            case 0: return ("Aguata");
            case 1: return ("Ekulobia");
            case 2: return ("Dike na fia");
            case 3: return ("Uli");
            case 4: return ("Aniche");
            case 5: return ("Achebe");
            case 6: return ("Akuwanta");
            case 7: return ("Ogbunike");
            case 8: return ("Obinohia");
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
package myprojets;
import java.awt.Color;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class erectTower extends GCompound {

    private static final Color RED = null;

    private GPolygon base;
    private GRect mast;
    public GPolygon flame;

    public erectTower(GLabel towerName) {
        base = creatBase();
        mast = new GRect(4.42,63.94 );
        flame = createFlame();
        add(base, 0,95);
        add(mast,5.29,20.44);
        add(flame,5.29,20.44);
        add(towerName, (base.getWidth() - towerName.getWidth())/2 , 115 );
    }

    private GPolygon creatBase() {
        GPolygon poly1 = new GPolygon();
        poly1.addVertex(0.0, 0.0);
        poly1.addEdge(5.29,-10.62);
        poly1.addEdge(4.42,0.0);
        poly1.addEdge(5.29,10.62);
        poly1.addEdge(-15,0.0);
        return poly1;
    }

    private GPolygon createFlame() {
        GPolygon poly2 = new GPolygon();
        poly2.addVertex(0.0,0.0);
        poly2.addEdge(-5.29,-10.44);
        poly2.addEdge(5.60,4.85);
        poly2.addEdge(1.90,-4.85);
        poly2.addEdge(1.9,4.85);
        poly2.addEdge(5.6,-4.85);
        poly2.addEdge(-5.29,10.44);
        poly2.addEdge(-4.42,0.0);
        poly2.setColor(Color.RED);
        return poly2;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Appart from this beeing bad code style it should work. What is the error? I'm guessing a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Forget the `NullPointerException` idea. Just discovered your array initialization. But still: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of `GCompound`s, not the class you created that extends `GCompound` (`erectTower`).

Change:

```
private GCompound[] name = { Aguata, Ekulobia, Dike_na_fia, Uli, Aniche, Achebe, Akuwanta, Ogbunike, Obinohia } ;
```

to

```
private erectTower[] name = { Aguata, Ekulobia, Dike_na_fia, Uli, Aniche, Achebe, Akuwanta, Ogbunike, Obinohia } ;
```

Along with all other references to `GCompound` so that you are using your own class.

Comment: Ah, so you aren't. My mistake haha

Answer (score 0):

While @Michael is right I try to explain this a little more. Your `name` array is of type `GCompound`. This means anything you access via `name[i]` has the static type `GCompund`. This means you only have access to the members of `GCompund`, even though the dynamic type at runtime would be `erectTower`. Lets make this more clear with using a local variable:

```
GCompound foo = name[i]; // works
foo.flame.setFilled(true); // won't work because foo is GCompound

erectTower bar = name[i]; // won't work without cast because array is of type GCompound
bar.flame.setFilled(true); // would work if bar was correctly assigned before
```

You can change the type of your array as @Michael suggested or you can cast your variable.

```
erectTower bar = (erectTower)name[i]; // works as long as all objects in your array are of type erectTower. Else it would throw a ClassCastException
bar.flame.setFilled(true) // works
```

You might want to read up on [polymorphism and static/dynamic type](http://www.sitepoint.com/quick-guide-to-polymorphism-in-java/).